# PfSense: redirection to authentication / login page from HTTPS links for unauthentified users

Tags: dns, https, redirection, pfsense

I've installed and configured pfsense 2.2.4

it works well and redirects unauthenticated users to the login page, as long as they use http; but when I type an https link the redirection doesnt work.

After lots of search I found that enabling https solves the issue but now i have an issue of certificates and users will always have that warning saying the web page is not secure. Which is unpleasant.

I found lately lets encrypt that gives free certificates. but This requires me to buy a domain name and for that i might need a public IP.( if i understand well)

All i need is that when a user is not authenticated, and type https://google.com it redirects it to the login page.

**EDIT: more details...**

without https enabled, if i try to access an http website redirection works but if i try https it just tells me the website is inaccessible, no redirect. but when i enable https for the login page then redirection works for both http and https however when the user lands on the login page (say 10.10.5.1/index.php) it is in https and the user get the warning of unsafe website.

Answer (score 1):

In short, this is impossible to avoid. Captive portal systems basically impersonate the real server in order to provide the redirect, and HTTPS is *specifically made* to prevent such impersonation.

The reason certificates are used in HTTPS is that they act as proof that the server you've connected to actually *owns* the domain name you entered. When you visit `https://google.com` the browser wants the server to prove that it is really `google.com` – and of course your pfSense captive portal server cannot do that, so the browser will always refuse to go any further.

It doesn't matter if you can get a certificate for *your own* domain and use it for the captive portal – it's still not the same domain that the browser is expecting to see. And it doesn't matter that you want to serve "only" a redirect, not a whole website – it still allows impersonating google.com, so it's still the same kind of security risk.

---

That said, many browsers and operating systems now perform "captive portal detection" – if they detect that *all* domains redirect to the same site, then instead of getting the red "bad certificate" message the user often gets a specific "this network requires a login" prompt that directly opens the captive-portal login page. So in many cases the user doesn't actually need to visit anything.

Comment: that's not the issue, without https enabled, if i try to access an http website redirection works but if i try https it just tells me the website is inaccessible, no redirect. but when i enable https for the login page then redirection works for both http and https however when the user lands on the login page (say https://10.10.5.1/index.php)  it is in https and the user get the warning of unsafe website. so IMHO I think with a certificate would solve the issue, but again would require a domain and public ip....